# Creating and copying text to multiple .cpp files in C++

Tags: c++, copying

So I'm doing the Euler Projects and I'm storing all my Solutions in one Program. I have just started on C++, so I don't know if this is a good way to do it. Anyway, each .cpp file contains one Problem. So basically my structure is like this:

"Executer.cpp"

```
include <iostream>
include "other.h"
int main() {

    Problem1();
    Problem2();
    // etc.
    system("pause")
    return 0;
}
```

"Other.h"

```
void Problem1();
void Problem2();
// etc.
```

"Problem_X.cpp" (X denotes the number of the task). I have a lot of these files.

```
/* PROBLEM X

*/

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>

void ProblemX() {
    time_t t1, t2;
    t1 = clock();

    // Code goes here

    t2 = clock();
    float diff((float)t2 - (float)t1);
    float seconds = diff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    // Results
    std::ofstream myFile("result.txt");
    //myFile << sum;
    myFile.close();

    std::cout << "--------------------  Problem X -------------------" << std::endl;


    std::cout << "I ran for: " << seconds << " seconds" << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

Now, the Projects consist of almost 600 Problems, which means I have to create 600 files and copy the template to each of those documents. So I thought I could just make a program for doing it.

Basically, I put "Problem_X.cpp" into a text file called "standard.txt". I then wrote the following program, which i run from my int main by including the function declaration in "other.h" and calling the function from "Executer.cpp". It runs fine when copying text from one text-file to another text-file. But now (I assume since I'm trying to copy into a .cpp file) nothing happens:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void CreateNewFile(int number)   // denotes the number of the problem you wish to create
{
    std::string strNumber = static_cast<std::ostringstream*>(&(std::ostringstream() << Number))->str();
    std::string str1 = "Problem_";
    std::string str2 = ".cpp";
    std::string strr;
    strr.append(str1); strr.append(strNumber); strr.append(str2);

    std::ofstream out(strr); //this creates it. 
    std::ifstream in("standard.txt");
    if (!out.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Can not open document2.txt" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(in, str)) {
        out << str << std::endl;
    }

    in.close(); 
    out.close(); 
}
```

Does anyone have experience doing something like this? I can't find any posts on google and I am out of ideas about where to look.

Answer (score 0):

The program actually runs as is is intended. It creates the new "Problem_X.cpp" files just right. They are just not imported in the VS source folder. If anyone has a quick solution for this, they are welcome to leave it in a comment here.

Comment: Seriously, I don't know what this line does `std::string strNumber = static_cast<std::ostringstream*>(&(std::ostringstream() << Number))->str();`. If you want to convert an integer to a string use this: `std::stringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    std::string strNumber = ss.str();` or if you are running C++11 or above use `std::to_string`

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi Thanks a lot! I will definitely implement that. I thought it was a rather complicated way of doing it, but it was what was recommended on www.cplusplus.com/forum :)